# filtering arrays with other lists

Tags: python, numpy, filtering

I have some numerical data with some features and a background.
I would like to remove the background, but I need to filter out the features first.
I have denoted a list with the starting and stopping X values (not the indices).
How should I get the XY data for these slices?

```
import numpy as np
# some strange inhomogenous step is used, so numpy slicing may be strange
x = range(0,36)
# starting and stopping x value segments that are probably background
bkg_ranges = [ [5., 15.], [28., 34.] ]

# this filter function doesn't work...
bkg_x = filter(lambda n: (np.logical_and(i[0]<=n, n<=i[1]) for i in bkg_ranges), x)

print 'input=', str(x)
print 'output=', str(bkg_x)
```

This code snippet will output:

```
input= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
output= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
```

I would like the output to be

```
[5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,   28,29,30,31,32,33,34]
```

As the bkg_ranges list denotes starting and stopping points along the input array (not indices but the sorted x values)

Comment: Can you show us some example input and output?

Comment: I added the output from the simple snippet.  It gives the same array and doesn't filter anything for some reason.

Comment: Can you show what you *want* the output to be too?

Comment: the thing is that since you're using a list comprehension in your filter function, you're returning a list of `[False/True, False/True]` which should be a value that is "Truthy", it doesn't filter anything for that reason.

Comment: You want the output to have no spaces between commas within each run, and multiple spaces between runs? How do you expect that to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this section here:

```
filter(lambda n: (np.logical_and(i[0]<=n, n<=i[1]) for i in bkg_ranges), x)
```

[`filter()` takes a function and an iterable and applies the function to each part of the iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter).

Now, looking at the above, we can see that functions return generators as you apply this `i[0]<=n<=i[1])` for each of the values in `bkg_ranges`. We can see this by using `map` to check the output:

```
>>> map(lambda n: (lambda n: (np.logical_and(i[0]<=n, n<=i[1]) for i in bkg_ranges), x)
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f12e1bfed70>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f12e1bfedc0>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f12e1bfee10>... ]
```

Now, since each of these generators *is* a thing, its truthy. Therefore when I apply the lambda function to the array `x`, every value has a truthy value, hence nothing is filtered out!

### What can you do instead:

Get rid of the generator:

```
>>> map(lambda n: (all(i[0]<=n<=i[1] for i in bkg_ranges)), x) # I Don't have numpy installed
[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False...]
```

All false. Why? Because there is no number that is both between 5 and 15 and also between 28 and 34.

Whay now? Well, you don't want a logical and, you want the filter to match [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any), not [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) values, so this should work:

```
>>> filter(lambda n: (any(i[0]<=n<=i[1] for i in bkg_ranges)), x)
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34]
```

Comment: Nice explanation, but it might be helpful to point him toward an answer as well.

Comment: @abernet I was getting to that. I was explaining the why first.

Comment: That was a fantastic explanation! I actually never thought about something returning 'true' just because it existed, or what everyone keeps calling "Truthy" here (never heard of that). 

I noticed that it had something to do with having an iterable because it worked fine with just values, but it didn't make sense as to why.

Comment: "Truthiness" is very important to understand in Python (and most languages). Generally, if something is `False` or `0` or empty, like `""` or `[]` they are "falsy", everything is "truthy".  Heres an interesting one... `[False]` is truthy, because its a non-empty array.

Comment: Most languages (e.g., C++ and Java) call it something like "evaluates to true when used in a boolean context" instead of "truthiness". There's a reason Steven Colbert inadvertently ripped off Guido rather than the ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG21 committee. :)

Comment: @abarnert All I know is what my gut tells me, and in my gut I believe that [Stephen Colbert invented truthiness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness).

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr: You're forgetting about [Guido's time machine](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/G/Guido.html). Even if Stephen Colbert _originally_ invented it first, Guido is still able to invent it first. (Apologies for the confusing tenses, but I don't have access to *Streetmentioner's Time Traveler's Handbook of 1001 Tenses*.) (Also, this has nothing to do with *Greedo* doing anything first or not.)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
# some strange inhomogenous step is used, so numpy slicing may be strange
x = np.arange(0,36)
# starting and stopping x value segments that are probably background
bkg_ranges = [ [5., 15.], [28., 34.] ]
np.concatenate([np.where((x >= start) & (x <= stop))[0]
                for start, stop in bkg_ranges])
```